# hibernate.cfg.xml not found - exception in java

Tags: java, hibernate

I am creating a simple application to learn Hibernate. I am using NetBeans IDE and I created a class in **com.hibernate** package. The class is defined as:

```
package com.hibernate;

import com.mahesh.entity.UserDetails; 

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory; 
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.classic.Session;

public class hibr {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
        user.setUserID(1);
        user.setUserName("Mahesh");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

I have defined UserDetails class as:

```
package com.mahesh.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

/**
 *
 * @author Mahesh
 */
@Entity
public class UserDetails {
    @Id
    private int userID;
    private String userName;

    public void setUserID(int userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public int getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
}
```

**I have defined a hibernate.cfg.xml file which is in src folder(default package)**

**This is the error generated by NetBeans IDE.**

> Feb 27, 2012 8:51:35 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
>   INFO: configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml Feb 27, 2012
>   8:51:35 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
>   INFO: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml Exception in thread
>   "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
>     at
>   org.hibernate.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:147)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:1405)
>     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1427)
>     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1414)
>     at com.hibernate.hibr.main(hibr.java:18) Java Result: 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
new Configuration().configure(<your cfg file path>).buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Please tell me path to write. i have my cfg file in src folder of NetBeans project

Comment: if you kept it in src folder then no need to give path, make sure that file from src copied in build folder of netbeans

Answer (score 1):

Make sure hibernate.cfg.xml also in your classpath in order that JVM can see it.

Comment: how to add hibernate.cfg.xml file in classpath i am working in NetBeans.

Comment: i try to add file path in system classpath but its working. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

```
new Configuration().configure()
```

The configure() is referring to the classpath in **build** folder. I used to copy it from the src folder to build folder manually. After clean, the build folder will be removed. So, I have to repeat it. Is there any way to automate this process?

I have considered

```
new Configuration().configure(new File("a path/hibernate.cfg.xml"))
```

But the hbm file descriptions in hibernate.cfg.xml also involve a resource path.
How can I mirror these files in build directory exactly as the source directory automatically?